# How to Handle Plain Javascript alert dialog buttons using Selenium with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, alert

I have **HTML page** like this,

```
<input type="button" id="btnlogin" value="Login" onclick="goToRegister()">
```

And the **javascript** is,

```
<script language="javscript" type="text/javascript">
    function goToRegister()
    {
        alert("Login Successful!");
        window.location.href="Register.html";
    }
</script>
```

In the **selenium script**,

```
  @Test
  public void goToRegisterPage()
  {
      System.out.println("goToRegisterPage");
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
      Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
      alert.accept();

      driver.get("file:///X://selenium//Register.html");
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod()
  {
      System.out.println("beforeMethod called " + visitcount++);

      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "X:\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      driver.get("file:///X://selenium//Login.html");
  }
```

**Scenario:**

When I execute these scripts using **TestNG Suite**, I'm getting the **Login** page and script is passing the credentials to username and password and finally clicks on the **Login** button.

After clicked login button, javascript alert appears...then I'm getting again the login page instead of **Register.html** :(

**Question:** How to handle this scenario?

Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi G

Comment: Try *window.location.assign("https://Register.html");*  Basically, add http:// to your URL

Comment: Hi MikeJRamsey56, Thank you for reply. I tried with your code but no luck. I'm getting the login page.

Comment: Karunagara, there is a confusion with your approach.

The JS method redirects the page to `Register.html` . Now again, in your selenium @Test, after `alert.accept()` you are doing navigation to the html yourself. 

Shouldn't there be a assertion of correct page instead of `driver.get()`?
Correct me if i understood it wrong.